# When I Want to Take Value From Shared Preferance then i Get Error

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

This Is The Code When I save My Value

```
 public static final String 
 MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
 public SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
 public static final String p = "pickLoc";
 public static final String Phone = "dropLoc";
 String pickLoc = pickupEt.getText().toString().trim();
 String dropLoc = dropEt.getText().toString().trim();
 sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(BookMyRide.this.MyPREFERENCES,
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
         editor.putString(p, pickLoc);
         editor.putString(Phone, dropLoc);
         editor.commit();
```

This Is The Code When i Want to Get Value

```
         try{
      sharedpreferences  = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      sharedpreferences.getString("pickLoc" ,"");
      sharedpreferences.getString("dropLoc","");
  }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Then it Throws the Exception :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Thanks In Advance For Helping Me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is the Context null? Can you debug and check which variable is null?

Comment: We need to see the surrounding class for the code that's crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this**

The Context in your activity may be null

**SharedPreference** without **PreferenceManager** !!!

***Check this sample***

To save *urValue* in SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, urValue);
        editor.apply();
```

To get name from SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String urValue = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "default value");
```

For more check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)